# Just gage - numbers show but not gage

Tags: css, raphael, justgage

I am using this code to make a gage with JustGage:

```
drawGage() {
    var g1 = new JustGage({
        id: "gage1",
        value: 90,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        levelColors: ["blue"],
        gaugeWidthScale: 0.9,
        startAnimationTime: 2700,
        startAnimationType: "bounce",
    });
}
```

I have these scripts in my index.html that load properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/raphael-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/justgage.js"></script>
```

and I have this div in my html that is being appended to:

```
<div id="gage1"></div>
```

this Image is what I end up with over and over again after trying a lot of different stuff:
[image]
When I inspect the SVG it looks like the `stroke` attribute on the `path` is being set to `none` for some reason, not sure why this is or if this is even my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer, but there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. This works, for example:

```
<html>
<script src="raphael-2.1.4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="justgage.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<body>
    <div id="gage1" class="200x160px"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawGage() {
        var g1 = new JustGage({
            id: "gage1",
            value: 90,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            levelColors: ["blue"],
            gaugeWidthScale: 0.9,
            startAnimationTime: 2700,
            startAnimationType: "bounce",
        });
    }
    drawGage();
</script>

</html>
```

So, it's got to be something else. Are you getting any errors on the page? In the console? Which browser are you using?